# Is it safe to delete old transaction logs after it created a new ones?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am running SQL Server 2014, my transaction log's size become very big size and it causing performance degradation.

I have created a new transaction log, and now the performance become normal.

My questions:

1. can I delete previous transaction log file?
2. is there any way to make it automatically create a new transaction log file after its size reached 1GB?

need advise.

many thanks in advance

Don

Comment: How did you create a new log file? 1GB is tiny. Do you do database backups? It will reset your log file anyway of you do.

Comment: I create a new transaction log file by right click the database-> file -> create new
I do backup to external harddisk but it does not reset the log file..
1GB is only example..

any comment or idea?

Comment: Just shrink the log file, no need to make a new one.  database > Tasks > Shrink > Files

Comment: is it safe to shrink it periodically?.. how about for mirrored database?

Comment: The log file will be "cleared" when you do your backup, but wont release space. The reasoning is that if your log file was 1GB before, then it will probably grow to the same again before your next backup, and it is more efficient to write into the log rather than having to extend it. If you want to shrink then doing that after a backup should reduce the space.